# How to give individual tiles their own collider in Unity's tilemaps?

Tags: unity, sprites, tilemap, collider

My floor tile is a 2D drawing of a 3D platform, for lack of a better description. I want my player character to stand not on the top of the tile but a little inside it, as the red circle does in the picture.

[image]

How do I give this tile its own collider that would fit this shape, while letting others have a normal, square one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your colliders on your tiles, reduce the offset from the top of the box.  So while it will render the whole image, only part of it will detect collision.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that, and it seems to work. Do I have to create another tilemap and put other, normal tiles there that would have an offset-less collider?

Comment: Depends on how you are doing your tile sets.  Assuming you are 9-slicing it, just change the collision boxes of the top 3 tiles.

Comment: 9-slicing? I'm a total beginner to game development, and this is my 3rd practice project. It's also my first time using tilemaps. So, instead of just up and creating a whole tileset, I created one tile (the one you see on the image), imported it and it alone, and shoved it into the tile palette. I didn't have to slice a large tileset.

Comment: are you using a library/tool/plugin to make your tiles?  Or is it just a bunch of GameObjects?

Comment: Just a PNG file I imported into Unity and then dragged into the tile palette window. No plugins or anything. I made the image in Aseprite.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using Unity's tilemap system.  Sorry, but I am not familiar with how to use it.  But I am guessing you have three options:  A.  No collider on a tile.  B.  Full collider on a tile.  C.  Custom collider on a tile.  Since you only have the one tile, you would just use a custom collider on it.  Then when you want to add a tile below that top tile, add a full collider to it.  (This is all assuming that their tilemap system works similar to others I've used.)

Comment: Creating another tilemap is a janky solution, but it should work. I'll mark this answer as correct if no better ones are given by tomorrow my time. Thank you.

Comment: Not create another tile map.  Just another tile within the map, with a different collider.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant: a new tilemap within the same grid. Unity terminology.